# What is a pseudotensor, really, and how to tell one?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensor-calculus, conventions, definition

I have some trouble with the concept of a "pseudotensor". Wikipedia distinguishes between that and a tensor density (e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density#Tensor_and_pseudotensor_densities), where both concepts are used simultaneously) while e.g. in Eric Weisstein's Mathworld [they say that](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudotensor.html)

> A pseudotensor is sometimes also called a tensor density.

These are two manifestly incompatible statements, and if asked, I'm inclined to believe that Wikipedia's definition of a pseudotensor, other than a synonyme for a tensor density, can not be rigorously formulated, i.e., no such thing exists. The purpose of this question is to confirm or refute this claim, mathematically. Some details follow to justify my case. "Pseudo" is used in its "Wikipedia" meaning: changing sign under inversion, whatever inversion means (discussed below).

**I would appreciate it if answerers read the question in full and consider my problem specifically (and using my "language", if possible)**, rather than going with "stock" definitions or examples. No "looking at something in a mirror" either unless you can put that into formulas and argue it's a passive or active transform of some kind. Also, bear in mind that the "usual" sources in your country / curriculum may not be readily available to me so I would greatly appreciate it if when citing them you could also quote the relevant part.

With this out of the way, I appreciate that all of these quantities are defined through formulas their elements in given coordinate systems undergo in transformations. However what most sources neglect is distinction between **passive** and **active** transforms, and, worse, between the [orientation of a vector space and an orientation of its basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)). For simplicity, let us only assume linear transforms of linear spaces; this should be WLOG for the purposes of the question as stated.

So, under a **passive** transform, one compares the decompositions of the same quantity in two bases $E = (e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ and $F = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, where $f_i = S^j_{\ i} e_j$, $S = (S^k_{\ l})_{k,l=1}^n \in GL(n)$. A $k$ times covariant and $l$ times contravariant tensor density $T$ of weight $w$ transforms, by the definition I know, as

$$\tilde T^{i_1,\ldots,i_l}_{j_1,\ldots,j_k} = (\det S)^w\ S^{m_1}_{\hphantom{m_1}j_1} \ldots S^{m_k}_{\hphantom{m_k}j_k}\ (S^{-1})^{i_1}_{\hphantom{i_1}n_1} \ldots (S^{-1})^{i_l}_{\hphantom{i_l}n_l}\ T\strut^{n_1, \ldots, n_l}_{m_1, \ldots, m_k}$$
where $T\strut^\ldots_\ldots$ and $\tilde T^\ldots_\ldots$ denote the components in $E$ and in $F$, respectively. (The sign convention of $w$ may differ.)

Since we are looking at the same object in a different systems of coordinates, there is no reason the *object* changes, only its *representation*. I've been told ([[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar), [[2]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudoscalar.html)) that a typical example of a pseudoscalar in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a triple product, $(\vec a,\vec b,\vec c) = \vec a \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c)$ since it "changes sign" under "inversion". Consider, though: in my notation, the inversion is just another $GL(n)$ matrix $S^i_{\ j} = -\delta^i_{\ j}$, and the "coordinate-less" definition of the triple product is
$$s := (a,b,c) = \omega(a,b,c)$$
where $\omega$ is a certain 3-form associated with the space, known as its volume form. In a "right-handed" orthonormal basis $E$, that is,
$$e_i \cdot e_j = \delta_{ij}, \qquad \omega(e_1,e_2,e_3) = +1,$$
the components of $\omega$ are
$$\omega_{ijk} = \epsilon_{ijk}$$
and thus we can express $s$ as
$$s = \omega_{ijk} a^i b^j c^k = \epsilon_{ijk} a^i b^j c^k.$$
If we now pick a basis $F = (-e_1,-e_2,-e_3)$ (which is left-handed), the quantity $s$ transforms as
$$\tilde s = \tilde w_{ijk} \tilde a^i \tilde b^j \tilde c^k,$$
where all of $a,b,c$ are contravariant and $\omega$ is fully covariant, so
$$\tilde a^i = -a^i, \quad \tilde b^j = -b^j, \quad \tilde c^k = -c^k$$
and also
$$\tilde \omega_{ijk} = (-1)^3 \omega_{ijk} = -\epsilon_{ijk}$$
by the above relation. Thus
$$\tilde s = -\epsilon_{ijk} (-a^i) (-b^j) (-c^k) = +\epsilon_{ijk} a^i b^j c^k = +s,$$
as expected. Of course, just looking at the **same quantity** (be it $s$, $\omega$, a cross product or anything else) in a **different basis** there is no reason the *quantity* should change, only perhaps its *numeric description* – that's what a passive transform means.

I'm not opposed to believing that $s$ *is* as pseudoscalar, but I'm firm in saying that a **passive transform can't manifest distinction from a proper scalar**. This is because although the orientation of two bases can easily differ, the [orientation of the space itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)) is its inherent property, unaffected by what basis we choose to decompose its elements, so *there are no "orientation-changing" passive* transforms. In other words, while the above result shows that $s$ is consistent with being a scalar (of density zero), it does not show it could not actually be a pseudoscalar, the coordinate inversion just did not test this because no change in orientation (of the space) actually took place.

(The very same reasoning works with no significant changes if $s$ is replaced by another typical example, the vector product, as defined using the Hodge star.)

This leaves **active** transforms that could possibly distinguish a pseudoscalar from a proper scalar. Well, defining (for comparison) $T = -\mathbb{I}$ and introducing **new** (actively transformed) **vectors**
$$A^i = T^i_j a_j = -\delta^i_{\ j} a_j = -a_i, \quad B^i = -b^i, \quad C^i = -c^i$$
and **their** triple product in the **original vector space**,
$$S = \omega(A,B,C) = \epsilon_{ijk} A^i B^j C^k = (-1)^3 \epsilon_{ijk} a^i b^j c^k,$$
we indeed obtain $-s$ (in accordance with the cited sources). But how is it justified to tell anything about the properties of $s$ when $S$ is a new quantity (only *defined* analogously)?

What's worse, if we take an "arbitrary" active transform given by a generic $T \in GL(n)$ and recompute $S = (A,B,C)$ for the images $A, B, C$, we get
$$S = \epsilon_{ijk}\ T^i_{\ p} T^j_{\ q} T^k_{\ r}\ a^p b^q c^r = \det T\ \epsilon_{pqr} a^p b^q c^r = \det T \cdot s,$$
so if we accept that $s$ is a pseudoscalar just because $S$ had a different sign for a particular choice of a $\det < 0$ matrix, we can see that the same reasoning would lead to $S$ changing its magnitude as well (making it actually behave *like* a scalar density, rather than a pseudoscalar, in terms of its transformation as expressed using $s$). One could argue that active transforms by $T \not\in O(3)$ are not physical, but then again – improper rotations can't be "reached" in real world any better than e.g. volume-nonpreserving ones.

Comment: More on [pseudo-tensors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+pseudo*+tensor*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume form $\omega$ is a legitimate rank-3 tensor. Hence $\omega(a,b,c)$ is a legitimate scalar, and indeed $\tilde{s} = +s$. When people say that the scalar triple product is a pseudoscalar, they must define it by
$$ a\cdot(b \times c) := \epsilon_{ijk}a^i b^j c^k \,,$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol – crucially, not the components of a legitimate rank-3 tensor.

Note that Mathworld is often flat-out wrong. In particular, in the first page you linked to, both instances of $\mathsf{A}$ should be replaced by $\mathsf{a}$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! But then, how would this ever be a scalar quantity under anything larger than $O(3)$, say, under scaling?

Comment: (This is the same question as in my last paragraph, as keeping the epsilon is just like transforming a,b,c only under the active transform. The problem then is why in general transforms, not limited to (+/–) rotations, *only* the sign should be changing. Otherwise it's not a pseudoscalar but a proper scalar density. Or if one restricts oneself to $O(3)$ there is no difference between the two concepts.)

Comment: @TheVee When people talk about the scalar triple product in this way they're most likely restricting attention to $O(3)$ tensors. However, one could easily extend the concept by allowing $\epsilon_{ijk}$ to transform under more general transformations than orthogonal ones. We would take precisely the pseudotensor transformation law, $\epsilon_{ijk} \to \mathrm{sgn}(\det S)S^l{}_{i} S^m{}_{j} S^n{}_{k} \epsilon_{lmn} = |\det S| \epsilon_{ijk}$.

Comment: Sure, I see. So one could say that taking a "pseudo" transformation law for $\epsilon$, we obtain a "pseudo" result. That's fair. The mathematical interpretation of this pseudo-3-form, as opposed to the volume form (with which it formally agrees in all positive bases), is eluding me, but then it's clear it would work this way. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You've already got there, but it seems that you're having trouble taking the consequences at face value. The thing that marks $s$ as a pseudoscalar is simply the transformation property
$$
S=\det(T)\cdot s,
$$
as you have derived it. However, you go a bit off-track when saying that this means that the magnitude of $S$ depends on the transformation, because the set of linear transformations $\mathrm{GL}(3)$ is just too big. The set of active transformations that can be said to implement equivalent physical situations is $\mathrm{O}(3)$, and there the magnitude of $S$ doesn't change since $|\det(T)| = 1$.

Moreover, $\mathrm{O}(3)$ splits into two distinct subsets, the subgroup $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ which can be reached with rigid rotations that can be physically implemented in the real world, and its coset $(-\mathbb I)\mathrm{SO}(3)$ which requires you to re-build a separate copy of your experiment with an opposite orientation. With that in mind, then:

- scalar quantities are those that are invariant under the full action of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, while
- pseudoscalar quantities are those that change their sign under the action of any active transformation drawn from the coset $(-\mathbb I)\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

The point that the coset $(-\mathbb I)\mathrm{SO}(3)$ can't be "reached" in the real world is precisely why we speak about a "mirror-world" experiment, i.e. a completely separate copy of the experiment that cannot be smoothly transformed into the original one.

Comment: Thank you! So for $O(n)$ there's really no difference between pseudotensors and tensor densities of (any) odd weight, and for $GL(n)$ the former isn't defined?

Comment: There's nothing special about the $\rm O(3)$-to-$\rm SO(3)$ distinction. You can do the same with $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ over the reals - it is the disjoint union of the subgroup $\mathrm{GL}^+(n)$ with positive determinant and its coset $(-\mathbb I)\mathrm{GL}^+(n)$, and you cannot smoothly reach the latter without squishing all space into a plane at some point.

Comment: (+1). Also (in the sense of my last sentence and your last paragraph), what justifies not saying that $O(3)$ is not "too big" either? My $SO(3)$ group preserves distances, angles *and* the right hand rule (or, $g_{ij}$ and $\omega_{ijk}$). I would say that breaking one is just as serious change in the model as breaking any other subset of these.

Comment: A transformation in $(-\mathbb I)\mathrm{SO}(3)$ specifies a recipe for taking an experiment and building a separate copy of it that's entirely identical as far as internal distances and angles, but with the quirk that it has 'opposite orientation' (cannot be rotated to match the original). In what way is this unphysical?

Comment: It's not unphysical. But I could also build an experiment that looks the same but is exactly twice as large in every direction (angles and orientation remain). And I believe that those quantities for which I had to adjust sign (to make physics work again), I also need to rescale them now by an odd power of det T (and some other quantities by even powers). That there are none which don't scale but get sign-reversed, it's always det T (density), not sgn det T (pseudo).

Comment: (Of course, this will likely break on microscopic scale, because I can't just rescale particles. But as far as I know, so will mirroring.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I agree with The Vee here. A scale transformation is no more or less physical than a rotation or reflection, and $S= (\det T) s$ is *not* the pseudoscalar transformation law, precisely because pseudoscalars should not change in magnitude when we perform a scale transformation. Such an object is what we mean by a (pseudo)scalar *density*.

Comment: I don't see what either of you is going on about. The question of whether and how tensors vs tensor densities scale with a scaling of the coordinates is completely orthogonal (in the precise sense that $\mathbb R^\times \cong \mathbb R^+\times \mathbb Z_2$) to the question of what the prefix "pseudo" means. None of this is special to O(3) or SO(3) or anything; the prefix "pseudo" is used to distinguish quantities that change sign under active transformations $T$ with $\det(T)<0$ versus quantities that don't.

Comment: The only objection that's been raised to that definition is that those are "unphysical" and the answer is that *yes*, they are unphysical, i.e. they cannot be implemented without taking the experiment apart and rebuilding it, which is where the talk of "looking at something in the mirror" comes from.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience, as it seems you can really help me clear this problem. I am very happy to accept this definition, it's just adding one more 1-dimensional representation into the mix, no problem. What I am unsure of is what physical quantities should be pseudotensors, as for the reasons here and above, I'm not convinced I've seen one yet. Meaning I *could* have something that changes sign only (or in addition to changing sign by being multiplied by a negative determinant), but none of the usual examples (vector products, moments, triple products) actually *do* so,

Comment: their sign change at inversion is a result by being multiplied by det $T$ which just happens to be $-1$, not explicitly by sgn det $T$. Meaning, in turn, it's a *definition* that could work nicely, but does not apply anywhere, as the examples that are given seem to be not pseudotensors but densities. So they *could* exist, the definition is OK and consistent, but it needs a real world example where they actually *do*, otherwise it's an unneeded addition to the theory.

Comment: But I guess I could ask a separate question about this.

Comment: @TheVee As I said, the issue of whether something is a density or not (i.e. whether it scales with $\det(T)$ or with $\mathrm{sgn}(\det(T))$ is a complete red herring, and it is entirely orthogonal to whether there is a sign change in the quantity when $\det(T)<0$ or not. All of the usual examples of pseudo-things have earned their pseudo suffix. If you're confused about how the details work out when you go from a tensor to a tensor density, then yeah, that's for a separate thread.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Here is the issue as I see it: the OP finds that any scalar quantity which changes sign under parity must also change size under rescaling. This seems puzzling, since we would expect quantities which experience sign changes but not rescalings to exist. You seem to escape this by just positing that $|\det T |$ must be one, which renders the whole concept of tensor density, and behaviour under rescaling, meaningless. But this is a useful concept! We should like to distinguish the transformation properties of charge, charge density, angular momentum, and angular momentum density.

Comment: @gj255 It's a useful concept, but it's orthogonal to the issue of parity. If you're already including a scaling weight $w$, then it's perfectly easy to posit a transformation law with a factor of $\mathrm{sign}(\det(T))^p|\det(T)|^w$ with weight $w$ and parity $p$, i.e. making explicit the homomorphism $Z(\mathrm{GL}(n))\cong \mathbb R^\times \cong \mathbb R^+\times \mathbb Z_2$ when enacting the group action. I seriously don't see the issue here.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The issue is simply that the OP finds that any pseudoscalar quantity is also necessarily a tensor density (with non-zero weight), which is false. The resolution lies not in the "physical" restriction to $|\det T|=1$ transformations as you claim in your answer, which renders the notion of density meaningless in any case, but rather in that the OP is using the *wrong transformation law* for the scalar triple product.

Comment: @gj255 Thanks, I was offline but this is exactly what I meant. You say my transformation law is wrong, I say it's nonstandard to redefine the Levi-Civita symbol, who knows — but it's becoming clear my definition of cross product using geometric / coordinate-agnostic terms (wedge product + Hodge dual) gives different results (that is, a vector) than yours (a pseudovector) while agreeing in positive-oriented ON bases and that's the source of all the difference.

Comment: I take back that any of the quantities mentioned above should be densities. That makes no sense at all, as it would have to show in passive transforms. They are proper tensors in the definition using $\omega$ and pseudotensors in the definition where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is replaced by a pseudotensor.